# Refactoring reducers and actions in a feature based architecture style

Tags: redux, next.js

This is a purely hypothetical example while I am trying to learn NextJs and I added Redux following the documentation from the [official link](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice)
but I want to format the code in a certain way, similar to feature based architecture where each feature is encapsulated in a separate folder.

***Please feel free to add, remove and suggest any changes, they are all most welcoming.***

This is my general folder structure

```
components
public
pages
|-accounts
| |-index.tsx
|-_app.tsx
|-index.tsx
store
|-account
| |-accountsApi.ts
| |-actions.ts
| |-index.ts
| |-reducer.ts
| |-types.ts
|-index.ts
styles
package.json
...
```

And this is the Accounts component under accounts folder at pages.

I am dispatching the login action from action creators, is there any way to make the action accept an object with the credentials?

```js
//pages/account/index.tsx
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useState } from 'react'
import Layout from '../../components/Layout'
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import type { Account } from '../../store/account/types'
import { accoutActions } from '../../store/account'

type Props = {
  accounts: Account[]
}

const Accounts: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ accounts }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
    let obj = {
      username: username,
      password: password
    }
    dispatch(accoutActions.login(obj)); // how to set it up, so that the action accepts an object with credentials
  }
  
  return (
    <Layout title="Accounts | Demo">
      <h1>Accounts</h1>
      <p>You are currently on: /accounts</p>
      <p>
        <Link href="/">
          <a>Go home</a>
        </Link>
      </p>
      <div>
        <p>Login</p>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
          <input onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} type="text" id="username" name="username" value={username} />
          <label htmlFor="password">Last name:</label>
          <input onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} type="text" id="password" name="password" value={password} />
          <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
export default Accounts
```

Below is my account store with its respective files:

`accountsAPI.ts` where the api calls to the server are made, I will try to refactor later in a singleton pattern using axios
however I am learning what NextJs allows and what not.

```js
import { CreateAccountInputModel, LoginInputModel } from "./types"
const url = 'https://127.0.0.1:8888/api/accounts'
export const createAccount = async (objModel: CreateAccountInputModel): Promise<any> => {
  const response = await fetch(`${url}/create`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(objModel),
  })
  const result = await response.json()
  return result
}
export const loginAccount = async(objModel: LoginInputModel): Promise<any> => {
  const response = await fetch(`${url}/login`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(objModel),
  })
  const result = await response.json()
  return result
}
export const logoutAccount = async () : Promise<any> => {
  const response = await fetch(`${url}/logout`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
  const result = await response.json()
  return result
}
```

`actions.ts` contains account actions

```js
import { createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { AccountActionTypes } from './types'

const create = createAction(AccountActionTypes.CREATE)
const login = createAction(AccountActionTypes.LOGIN)
const logout = createAction(AccountActionTypes.LOGOUT)

export const actionCreators = {
    create,
    login,
    logout,
};
```

`index.ts` where I combine reducer from the reducer file and make a slice so that I can join all reducers to the store

I want to be able the reducers in a separate file

```js
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { CreateAccountInputModel } from './types'
import type { AppState, AppThunk } from '..'
import { createAccount, loginAccount, logoutAccount } from './accountsAPI'
import { reducer, initialState } from './reducer'

export const createAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  'account/create',
  async (objModel: CreateAccountInputModel) => {
    const response = await createAccount(objModel)
    // The value we return becomes the `fulfilled` action payload
    return response.data
  }
)
export const accountSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'account',
  initialState,
  reducers: reducer, // error: Type 'ReducerWithInitialState<AccountState>' is not assignable to type 'ValidateSliceCaseReducers<AccountState, SliceCaseReducers<AccountState>>'.
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(createAsync.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading'
      })
      .addCase(createAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'idle'
      })
  },
})

export { actionCreators as accoutActions } from './actions';
export const isAuthenticated = (state: AppState) => state.account.isAuthenticated
export default accountSlice.reducer
```

Here are reducers `reducer.ts` and the initial state of the given reducer

```js
import { createReducer, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { actionCreators } from './actions';
import { Account, AccountState } from './types';

export const initialState: AccountState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  token: '',
  status: 'idle',
  accounts: [] as Account[],
}

export const reducer = createReducer(initialState, (builder) => {
  builder
    .addCase(actionCreators.login, (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = action.payload.isAuthenticated
      state.token = action.payload.token
      // can I do, return { ...state, ...} so that the previous state is preserved?
    })
    .addCase(actionCreators.logout, (state, action) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = false
    })
    .addCase(actionCreators.create, (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
      state.accounts = [...state.accounts, action.payload]
    }).addDefaultCase((state, action) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = false
      state.token = ''
    })
})
```

All the types and models are stored in `types.ts` file.

**I can write `types.ts` if it is required, but you can assume a general case of an account.**

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to make the action accept an object with the credentials?

```
const login = createAction<TypeOfObjectWithCredentials>(AccountActionTypes.LOGIN)
```

Calling `login` with an object will put it inside the `payload` automatically.

Comment: I still get the error `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1`

Comment: This is what the redux toolkit documentation says about `createAction`, maybe check their github issues?